# wpf app appears to be blocking extended screen functionality on hp laptop

Tags: wpf, multiple-monitors

I ran into a strange issue where "fn_key -- F4" combination on my hp laptop to extend the screen would stop working once I have a wpf application running. This happens even when I create an empty app -- as soon as I run it, I can't extend my desktop to a second monitor.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a driver issue (as Drew mentioned above).

To diagnose an issue like this, please follow the instructions from the MSDN article (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970912.aspx) on how to disable hardware acceleration and render everything in software.

Provided your issue is similar to what I have experienced, you will be able to single out the problem by adding the necessary registry key from the article.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an issue with your video driver. What kind of video card is it? Are you running the latest drivers from the vendor?

Comment: Drew, latest video drivers. not sure how loading wpf app would prevent multiple screen  operation.